# PHP can't connect to Sphinx on Live Site

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I get the error "Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:9306' (0)".  According to the netstat command the port 9306 is open but it can't connect via PHP or the command prompt.  The command prompt connects to MySQL on port 9306 instead of connecting to sphinx.

The code that causes this is:

```
$sphinx = new mysqli('127.0.0.1:9306');
```

This is on Linux and the Sphinx version is 2.0.4.  Other versions including 2.2.1 have been tried.

Can anyone help me get this working?

This is my first question so let me know if I need to change the format of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re the command-line client, you probably need to explicitally tell it use tcp

```
mysql -P 9306 --protocol=tcp
```

Its counter-intutive, that the mysql client will silentiy ignore the -P param, if it finds a mysql server on the local machine.

And as for PHP, no idea if what you have should work, but I tend to use

```
$sphinx = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "", "", "", 9306);
```

which works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Everything works now.  I'm not sure why the '127.0.0.1:9306' worked on my personal computer but what you use worked perfectly. Would upvote if I could!